# angular.fromJson not working properly

Tags: angularjs, json

The code is as follows

```
var taskString = window.localStorage['tasks'];

if(taskString) {
  var tasks = angular.fromJson(taskString);
  console.log(tasks);
}
```

I had a json format string stored in the **window.localStorage['tasks']**, which is like this

```
[{"title":"a"},{"title":"b"},{"title":"c"}]
```

so that the `var taskString` would be exactly `[{"title":"a"},{"title":"b"},{"title":"c"}]`

in the code I tried to parse this string into a json array `tasks`, and the array should contain three objects with the title attribute set separately as **a, b and c**

but the problem here is, after the execution of `angular.fromJson(taskString)`, I print the array out to the console, and in the array the titles become **b,c, and `undefined`**

Is this a bug of that funciton? Or did I mistankenly do something I shouldn't have in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle of this

Comment: No problem with `angular.fromJson` its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine. Look at the following example snippet. I emulated `localStorage` as `storage`.

Check for any silly mistakes or if you are setting it properly.

```js
var storage = {
  setItem: function(name, item) {
    this[name] = item
  }
}

storage.setItem('tasks', '[{"title":"a"},{"title":"b"},{"title":"c"}]')
var taskString = storage['tasks'];

if (taskString) {
  var tasks = angular.fromJson(taskString);
  console.log(tasks);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks.....it was not the problem of the code I posted. Somewhrere else I called tasks.splice and the parameter was not set right....What a silly mistake

Comment: @RushSykes happens.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = '[{"title":"a"},{"title":"b"},{"title":"c"}]';
var obj = angular.fromJson(json);
console.log(obj);
```

Works fine for me, below is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n8ezb7sg/89/